# Parent - child scope hierarchy when defining Angular directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am learning AngularJS at the moment and was reading about the ways of binding the variables from the parent scope of a directive to the isolated scope of a directive. I have some understanding issues regarding the scope hierarchy.

There is the simple and working color-picker directive example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="colorPickerApp">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  ...
</head>
<body>    
  <h1>AngularJS Colorpicker</h1>

  <color-picker init-r="255"
    init-g="0"
    init-b="123"
    init-a="0.7"
    on-change="onColorChange(r, g, b, a)">
  </color-picker>    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="colorPickerApp.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**colorPickerApp.js**

```
var colorPickerApp = angular.module('colorPickerApp', []);

colorPickerApp.directive('colorPicker', function(){
  return {
    scope: {
      r: '@initR', // init-r <==> initR
      g: '@initG',
      b: '@initB',
      a: '@initA',
      onChange: '&'
    },
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: './ColorPicker.html',
  };
});
```

**ColorPicker.html**

```
Red channel:<input type="range" min="0" max= "255" step="1" ng-model="r"><br>
Green channel:<input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" ng-model="g"><br>
Blue channel:<input type="range" min="0" max="255" step="1" ng-model="b"><br>
Alpha channel:<input type="range" min="0" max="1" step="0.01" ng-model="a">
<div style="width: 300px; height: 100px; background-color: rgba( {{r}}, {{g}}, {{b}}, {{a}});">
<div>
```

So, apparently, the *initR/G/B/A* comes from the parent scope of the directive. By definition, a scope is a *" ... set of variables or functions defined in a certain context. The context is a certain part of a DOM"* 
My template is instantiated in the **index.html** with those attribute. I do not understand what makes them to the parent scope of the directive ?

--- EDIT ---
To make my confusion more clear I create following image:
[image]

- The attributes used for the color-picker initialization are nowhere declared as a part of a controller. Am I able to access those attribute somewhere else ?
- I would expect, that the color-picker scope - the red one would be the scope of the directive. But the directive access those attributes in its parent scope. So, the red-scope is actually the blue-one ???

Comment: for example, you can't send [scope.x] from [childController] to [parentController] that because [scope.x] not define in your [parentController], in this case first you have to define [scope.x] in your controller and then send it to the directive to make changes and then return it to the controller again to get scope results.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but no controller with no explicite model declaration ($scope.x) is used in this example. I just found this example in a AngularJS book.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an explanation to my question. The linking between the *attributes of the isolated scope* of a directive and a *outer world*, done in the **scope:** object using the **@ = &** operators (prefixes) creates a relation between the **isolated scope and the attributes of the directive** which can be further instantiated from the *parent scope*

The [Angular Wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) says following to this topic:

> ... directives often need access to a few parent scope properties. The object hash is used to set up two-way binding (using '=') or one-way binding (using '@') between the parent scope and the isolate scope. There is also '&' to bind to parent scope expressions. So, these all create local scope properties that are derived from the parent scope. Note that attributes are used to help set up the binding -- you can't just reference parent scope property names in the object hash, you have to use an attribute. E.g., this won't work if you want to bind to parent property parentProp in the isolated scope:  and scope: { localProp: '@parentProp' }. An attribute must be used to specify each parent property that the directive wants to bind to:  and scope: { localProp: '@theParentProp' }.

I think, this should be better explained [in the book](http://www.angularjs-buch.de/) I am reading, which describes the linking as a *link between the isolated scope and the parent scope*. In fact this is done using an **intermediate stage: isolated scope <=> directives attributes <=> parent scope**

Umur Kontaci also created [some helpful examples](https://blog.umur.io/2013/07/02/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/) to this topic.